# Accent and case insensitive COLLATE equivalent in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-like, case-insensitive

In Microsoft SQL Server, if I want to search case insensitively in a case-sensitive database, I can run the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField = 'BobDillon' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

And that will find all "bobdillon" entries.

If I want to do the same in Oracle, I know I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE UPPER(MyField) = 'BOBDILLON'
```

But I want to know if there is a direct equivalent to the collate keyword, so I can search for case sensitivity and accent sensitivity as I see fit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NLSSORT(MyField, 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI') = NLSSORT('BobDillon', 'NLS_SORT = Latin_AI')
```

Comment: Should be `Latin_AI` so that it's also accent-insensitive.

Comment: This really work!!!

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1117030?start=0&tstart=0) you can do the following:

```
select * from your_table 
where utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2((nlssort(your_column, 'nls_sort=binary_ai'))) like lower('%word%')
```