# Case sensitive duplicate values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table with the below sample records

```
Name    Profession      University
-----   --------------  ---------------
Ram     Student         xxxUniversity
Ravi    Professor       xyzUniversity
Reshma  Professor       abcUniversity
Ram     StudenT         xxxUniversity
```

As seen above "Ram" has case sensitive duplicate records. My Oracle query should return distinct records and one record for "Ram", which has the maximum number of uppercase character in Profession column.

Expected result

```
    Name    Profession      University
    -----   --------------  ---------------
    Ravi    Professor       xyzUniversity
    Reshma  Professor       abcUniversity
    Ram     StudenT         xxxUniversity
```

Comment: Can you use a case insensitive collation in Oracle?

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507504/accent-and-case-insensitive-collate-equivalent-in-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT name,
       Profession,
       university
FROM
(SELECT name,
       Profession,
       university,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,UPPER(PROFESSION) ORDER BY REGEXP_COUNT (Profession, '[A-Z]') DESC) RN
  FROM table1)
WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the row number partitioned over the unique values for each column converted to upper (or lower) case:

```
SELECT name, profession, university
FROM   (
  SELECT name, profession, university,
         ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY
               UPPER( name ),
               UPPER( profession ),
               UPPER( university )
             ORDER BY
               LENGTH( TRANSLATE( profession, ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ' ' ) ) DESC
           )
           AS rn
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: ORDER BY missing in ROW_NUMBER()